# regex to match a string or an abbreviation thereof

Tags: regex

For writing a parser I need to be able to identify keywords which can be abbreviated,
for example

MY-KEYWORD

should at least be MY-KEY but can also be any abbreviation longer than this, here specifically MY-KEYW, MY-KEYWO, MY-KEYWOR or the full MY-KEYWORD.

For the life of me, no regex I tried so far (and that were many ...) matches exact substrings of something with a minimum length :-(

TIA !

Alex

Comment: Are you sure regex is the right tool for the job? Read one character at a time until you reach the end of the token or encounter an invalid continuation.

Comment: For the whole thing it is definitely not the right tool, but for a subset it might be, once I know is it reasonably possible at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the prefix and then optional characters after it to finish the full keyword.

```
\bMY-KEY(?:W(?:O(?:RD?)?)?\b
```

All the groups are needed to ensure that no optional letters are skipped. If you wrote `MY-KEYW?O?R?D` it would match `MY-KEYD`.